# CLEAR command in python discord bot is not working properly

Tags: python, discord.py

i am a very beginner in biscord bot things, the problem that i get with everything i tryed on the web for what i need is that clear is not working in anyway, here is the code that i am stuck with

```
from turtle import clear
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import client
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import bot
token = "what are you watching"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("?"))
async def clear(ctx, number):
    mgs = []
    number = int(number)
    async for x in client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number):
        mgs.append(x)
    await client.delete_messages(mgs)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: What's wrong with the code? What do you want it to do, and what does it actually do? What is the error message?

Comment: i cannot deleate chat message from the discord chat with that code and it is what it should do._.

Comment: That doesn't give any information. What is the error message (or is there none displayed)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: in Client: don't use tuples inside the command_prefix (just type "?")

secondly: you need a decorator @client.command()

finally: you can use just await ctx;channel.purge(limit=number)
so the command part will look like this

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx,number):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number)
```

Bonus Info:
import the commands module from discord.ext (from discord.ext import commands)
and add this line below @client.command()

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
```

This will [check if the user of the command has the permission to manage channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions).

Every permission you can type is in the attributes list in:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions

Comment: hi, thank you for answering but it still does not work qwq
from turtle import clear
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import client
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import bot

print("sto andando online")
token = "OTc1MzIzODQ0ODA4MTU5MjQz.GHGMCk.B09w16t-Cvo7YHwqoOngfT_eGqPByUcfl3vJQQ"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("?"))
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def clear(ctx,number):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number)

client.run(token)

Comment: You should reset the token because you just posted it @lollingameWGF

Comment: @lollingameWGF you should remove the "from turtule import clear" because its overwrite you're command